# How to access room number and device name from tizen 4

Tags: tizen

The webapis.network.getTVName(); returns the room number set on the tizen 6 HAU Hospitality tv's but the older versions have different fields for setting room number and device name. The function does not work on the tizen 4 modal. Does anyone know what the webapi or function is for retrieving room number from a tizen 4 hospitality tv.

Comment: Hello, have you checked the reference page?https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/network-api.html#NetworkManager-getTVName

Comment: Yes I have read thru most of the documentation.